# Material-UI: Bottom Navigation Not Showing at the bottom of the page

Tags: material-ui

I am trying to use the [Bottom Navigation](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/bottom-navigation), but it appears not showing at the bottom of the page. Instead it is showing relative with its above DOM.

Do we have to build separate layout and inject the Bottom Navigation Component to the fixed bottom position?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You have not shown your code.But I think you are using relative layout.Change the layout to Linear Layout and check.